# unresolved external symbol _glGenBuffers error

Tags: c, opengl, unresolved-external

I am trying to follow this tutorial: http://playcontrol.net/ewing/jibberjabber/opengl_vertex_buffer_object.html

And I have received this error:
unresolved external symbol _glGenBuffers

After having done some research I have found that Windows only supports OpenGL 1.1 unless drivers are installed. I have Intel HD Graphics with the latest drivers supporting OpenGL 2.1. I have also read that glGenBuffers was made apart of OpenGL in version 1.5. I am not understand why I am getting these errors...

After running the driver check on Intel's website I got this message:

Product Detected     Intel® HD Graphics
Current Driver Installed     8.15.10.2361
Your driver is current.

I have heard of some external libraries that help with this (glee or glew), but I do not want to use more libraries, I simply want to fix this problem by using the version of OpenGL that my graphics card supports...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have basically provided your own answer. Windows indeed supports only OpenGL 1.1 entrypoints. This has nothing to do with whatever functionality your GPU/driver supports.

For anything in later versions of OpenGL you would either have to resort to loading them yourself via wglGetProcAddress (Bad idea) or by using something like [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/). With GLEW you'll be able to easily query which extension are available and it takes a lot of pain out of the equation.

It's a very simple and small library and I would choose it any day over having to mess with this myself.

Comment: hrmm. Okay, thank you. I'll bite the bullet on this one then.

Comment: Just for fun have a look at what GLEW is doing behind the scenes and ask yourself if you want to mess with that. ;) Good luck.